# Getting " \n " in websocket / SignalR response?

Tags: ios, objective-c, websocket, signalr

I am getting " \n " in a websocket / SignalR response and I can't seem to figure out why. I have tried changing my data type for the response object, parsing it as if it were JSON, but still can't get rid of the " \n ".

How can I remove this " \n " and handle this like any other JSON object / response?

Code for reference:

```
-(void)SignalR{

    WebServices *services = [[WebServices alloc] init];

    SRHubConnection *hubConnection = [SRHubConnection connectionWithURLString:@"xxx"];

    SRHubProxy *proxy = [hubConnection createHubProxy:@"xxx"];

    [services callGetSRAlertGroupNames:^(NSMutableArray *alertGroupNameArray){
        NSLog(@"SR ALERT GROUP NAMES: %@", alertGroupNameArray);

        [services callGetSRNotificationGroupNames:^(NSMutableArray *notificationGroupNameArray) {
            NSLog(@"SR NOTIFICATION GROUP NAMES: %@", notificationGroupNameArray);

            NSArray *combinedArray=[alertGroupNameArray arrayByAddingObjectsFromArray:notificationGroupNameArray];

            // Register for connection lifecycle events
            [hubConnection setStarted:^{

                NSLog(@"Connection Started");

                for (NSString *groupName in combinedArray ){
                    [proxy invoke:@"Subscribe" withArgs:@[groupName] completionHandler:nil];
                }

            }];
            [hubConnection setReceived:^(NSString *data) {

                NSLog(@"CONNECTION RECIEVED - %@",data);

            }];
            [hubConnection setConnectionSlow:^{
                NSLog(@"Connection Slow");
            }];
            [hubConnection setReconnecting:^{
                NSLog(@"Connection Reconnecting");
            }];
            [hubConnection setReconnected:^{
                NSLog(@"Connection Reconnected");
            }];
            [hubConnection setClosed:^{
                NSLog(@"Connection Closed");
            }];
            [hubConnection setError:^(NSError *error) {
                NSLog(@"Connection Error %@",error);
            }];

            [hubConnection start];

        }];
    }];
}
```

Logged out response sample:

```
CONNECTION RECIEVED - {
    A =     (
        "{
\n  \"NotificationType\": 1,
\n  \"TelemetryDetails\": {
\n    \"serialNumber\": \"xxx\",
\n    \"name\": \"sf-top\",
\n    \"statusId\": 2,
\n    \"buildVersion\": \"xxx\",
\n    \"securityModeId\": 2,
\n    \"IP\": \"xxx\",
\n    \"priority\": 1,
\n    \"bandwidthUpload\": 0.00,
\n    \"bandwidthDownload\": 0.00,
\n    \"bandwidthInternal\": null,
\n    \"totalBandwidthUpload\": 3107397.00,
\n    \"totalBandwidthDownload\": 8078656.00,
\n    \"totalBandwidthInternal\": null,
\n    \"usage\": \"8078656/3107397\",
\n    \"lastUpdateTime\": \"2017-03-02T16:27:57.1736937Z\",
\n    \"buildVersionUpdatingInProgress\": false,
\n    \"transportType\": 2,
```

Comment: From my experience that isn't a normal response with Signal R. There is a chance that is how your backend is set up to send you the information -- have you checked to rule that out?

Answer (score 1):

Simple.

You can use :

```
data = [data stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"\n" withString:@""];
```

But this trick is "dirty" because the problem is obviously coming from your web service, I guess.

**EDIT:**

Where are you replacing occurrences ?

Can you tell me what does this log ?

```
[hubConnection setReceived:^(NSString *data) {

      NSLog(@"CONNECTION RECIEVED - %@",data);
      NSString *newString = [data stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"\n" withString:@""];
      NSLog(@"NEW STRING - %@", newString);
  }];
```

**EDIT 2:**

Ok can you try to add this variable outside the completion handler.

```
__block NSString *newString;
```

Or you can also try this

```
[hubConnection setReceived:^(NSString *data) {

          NSLog(@"CONNECTION RECIEVED - %@",data);

          [self replaceOccurrences: data];

}];

- (void)replaceOccurrences:(NSString *)data {
    NSString *newString = [data stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"\n" withString:@""];
    NSLog("New String = %@", newString);
}
```

But you really should check your backend, this response is not in an appropriate format.

Comment: Unfortunately it broke on this line, indicating it's a dictionary. If I make my data object a NSDictionary, I still get the "  \n " if I log that dictionary. Problem may be with the way the data is being sent.

Comment: That statement causes the following error: -[__NSDictionaryI stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:withString:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x6180002665c0